# How to use join query in SQL using X-devAPI and nodejs?

Tags: sql, node.js, relational-database, mysql-connector

I am using NodeJs. connector X-devAPI for writing queries. I need to use a join query . How do I write query ?

```
const session = mySqlx.getSession(config);
 const schema = await session.getSchema('xxxx');
  let tableresp = await schema.getTable('tableName');
        tableresp = await tableresp
            .select(['id', 'name', 'Mobile'])
            .execute(function (row) {
               console.log(row)
            });
```

Answer (score 6):

At the moment you have to use plain SQL queries.

```
await session.sql('SELECT id, name, Mobile FROM xxxx.tableName JOIN ...').execute()
```

Sorry for the late answer. Your question didn't show up in the tags I was watching.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead dev of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js